# Crossbrowser onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, onbeforeunload

Does [`window.onbeforeunload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.onbeforeunload) fire in all browsers? I need a onbeforeunload functionality which is supported at least by IE6 and FF3.6.

For IE, `onbeforeunload()` seems only to be [supported by IE9](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Šime Vidas cool! Thanks that code will be very useful!

Comment: @Šime Vidas, did not found anything useful in https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js :(

Comment: `onbeforeunload` is in that script. Use CTRL + F to search...

Comment: @powtac : Have you finished your tests ?

Comment: @powtac : take your time and ask, if you need help

Comment: @Aelios still no. :-/ Do you want to create a test fiddle?

Comment: @powtac : do you need to add a custom message on last alert ?

Comment: @Aelios a default browser notice would be ok.

Comment: MSDN says it's supported on IE9+ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974336(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: see browser support of `onbeforeunload` WindowEventHandler on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I've got a clean solution working cross browser please accept my answer

Comment: @powtac, I think Aelios went above and beyond to answer your question and to stay engaged on this question as you let the years roll past. Are you really still "testing" or just not willing to accept an answer?

Answer (score 15):

I found a workaround for Firefox with `setTimeout` function because it does not have the same behaviour as other web browsers.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    var message = "Are you sure ?";
    var firefox = /Firefox[\/\s](\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent);

    if (firefox) {
        //Add custom dialog
        //Firefox does not accept window.showModalDialog(), window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() furthermore
        var dialog = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(dialog);
        dialog.id = "dialog";
        dialog.style.visibility = "hidden";
        dialog.innerHTML = message; 
        var left = document.body.clientWidth / 2 - dialog.clientWidth / 2;
        dialog.style.left = left + "px";
        dialog.style.visibility = "visible";  
        var shadow = document.createElement("div");
        document.body.appendChild(shadow);
        shadow.id = "shadow";       
        //tip with setTimeout
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("dialog"));
            document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("shadow"));
        }, 0);
    }

    return message;
}
```

GitHub: https://github.com/Aelios/crossbrowser-onbeforeunload

Comment: What does it mean `not seem to catch onbeforeunload event` the native onbeforeunload event if there is one?

Comment: In fact, Opera does not know onbeforeunload event, that's all

Comment: on Chromium, this pops up a confirm dialog for me. However, if I `return null`, then it doesn't.

Comment: Cool solution! if you want add a link back from Github to this discussion, to keep the knowledge in this discussions connected...

Comment: @Aelios, will this cause browsers like Opera to fire the `onbeforeunload` event before unloading?

Comment: @KyleMit : I do not have any solution for Opera yet, as it does not implement `onbeforeunload` event.

Comment: cross-browser solution for IE 11, Edge, Chrome and Firefox ?

Answer (score 6):

No it does not fire in all browsers. It's not supported in mobile browsers e.g. Safari, Opera Mobile & mini, Dolphin. See [Is there an alternative method to use onbeforeunload in mobile safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205989/is-there-an-alternative-method-to-use-onbeforeunload-in-mobile-safari)

Comment: Yes it does. The OP asked "Does window.onbeforeunload() fire in all browsers?" and my answer is "it's not supported in mobile browsers".

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Whilst I agree generally, in this case my answer does include the essential parts of the linked article (not supported in mobile browsers), plus I am linking to SO so there is no danger of the link becoming invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon Tushar Ahirrao solution this works cross browser and triggers once (Works in Firefox, Chrome, whatever)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = {};
app.unloaded = false;
app.unload = function() {
    if (app.unloaded) return; else app.unloaded = true;
    // your code here
    return "YO";
};
</script>
</head>
<body onunload="return app.unload();" onbeforeunload="return app.unload();">
YO
</body>
</html>
```

Paste above template to empty file then edit it

Answer (score 1):

It's my recollection that IE was the only browser to implement `onbeforeunload`, but some browsers have taken it upon themselves to implement it.

Long story short, IE is about the only browser (with very finite exceptions) you'll find this event consistently in.

Comment: Given it's a microsoft product, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be a great place to start.

Comment: Yes I saw this page already, but I don't see any information about the support of IE versions on it, or do I miss something?

Comment: @powtac: I believe it goes pretty far back (though I remember issues arising in IE8 with this event). You can also [test for support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158673/onbeforeunload-support-detection) and bind when found and default when absent.

Answer (score -6):

Then you can use both  like this :

```
<body onunload="functionName();" onbeforeunload='functionName();' >
```

Comment: But browsers which support both events will execute things twice.

Comment: @pimvdb..then use one flag ..if its true then excute function, once it is executed then make it false.

Comment: This answer is too raw. Needs explanation, as it is, it's not very helpful.

Comment: A function with a var to check if it already fired would be alright here.