# Built in function when popup window is closed?

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I have been researching intently and have been unable to find a solution to my problem.  I have a 'home' page and you can select a button that generates a popup window called 'test'.  Now if I close the popup window is I want it to instantly do something on my homepage, like write "Hello World".  Is there a built in function that checks if the window is closed?  I have come across many self made links with self made functions called window.close.  Here is the code I have that generates the popup window.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$var = "<a href='JavaScript:newPopup(\"http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/register.html\");' class='two'>Register</a> | <a href='JavaScript:newPopup(\"http://www.yourfantasyfootballreality.com/signin.php\");' class='two'>Sign In</a>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.onbeforeunload).

Also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389554/crossbrowser-onbeforeunload).