# customise firefox popup box using javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, onbeforeunload

When a user tries to close the browser window a popup box pops up. But the problem with that is, it displays its own popup data. So please let me know how can I customize it content of popup box in "Firefox".

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      return "my text";
 };
```

Here instead of "my text" it is displaying its own data.
Note: its working fine in Chrome!

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389554/crossbrowser-onbeforeunload/10812296

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't... not in `FF`

> Note that in Firefox 4 and later the returned string ***is not displayed***
>   to the user. [See bug 588292](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292).*

The only solution is create a custom `modal box` and give some `CSS` style to that `DIV` (for example...)

[Source: developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload)

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot for your answer. will surely try with custom modal box.

Comment: Glad to help.. look here, could be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/tags/onbeforeunload/hot

Comment: oh Thanks a lot for that link..your answer was really very helpful..I wish i could vote up but not enough reputation :P

Comment: Don't worry, we are here to help and learn from each other, not for the points `;)`

Comment: @Pooja, now you can upvote and/or accept this also :)

Comment: @sergio: haha ok sure thanks for that piece of information :)