# beforeunload in not working when closing the tab

Tags: jquery

I want to execute some code when user close their browser. I found some piece of code and try it, but it is not working. I notice that it is working when I am clicking on Run link at jsfiddle. I dont know why.

```
$(function(){
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    alert(0)    
})  
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vacLcray/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crossbrowser onbeforeunload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389554/crossbrowser-onbeforeunload)

Comment: working for me but you should try out of fiddle, seem be blocked.

Comment: whats about using pure [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload) ?

Comment: you can only return a string in that handler

Answer (score 0):

> when the beforeunload event is triggered generates an default alert

```
$(function(){
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){   
 return 'message';
 });  
});
```

> you can override the message like the above code sample