# Refresh page after delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm catching the page close/refresh event by following code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  jQuery("#submit_form_button").click();
  jQuery("#saving_loader").show();
};
```

Here, the line `jQuery("#submit_form_button").click();`sends a request to **controller#update** method and saves the form before reload. The only problem is, it works sometimes and sometimes not. Specifically I'm seeing this problem in Chrome.

So I want to delay the refresh process. It should happen after `click()` event. I tried setTimeout() but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you tried `setTimeout`? How you tried? Post your trial!

Comment: `setTimeout` runs code in the global scope so it won't have access to the variables in the context if you have variable names in the string, also, *Chrome* does not allow cookies to save when run from a local file on your computer unless you open *Chrome* with a special flag. so if you are saving your form in cookies it won't appear in *Chrome*

Comment: @Sarfaraaz I'm not saving form in cookies. When the page refreshes, it sends the **current page url** again to controller and renders same page again. My idea is to send an update request before request with **current page url** hits controller

Comment: I think `beforeunload` must return a string before closing the window.. take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389554/crossbrowser-onbeforeunload

Comment: _"So I want to delay the refresh process. It should happen after click() event. I tried setTimeout() but it doesn't work."_ Would `window` be closed when `duration` of `setTimeout` reached ?

Comment: or you can use jQuery http://stackoverflow.com/a/18822757/536532

Comment: @DanielAlmeida Thanks. I had already tried your first suggestion. The problem is **return** STRING will open a popup which I don't want. All the saving should happen silently.

Comment: I visited a website some time ago they put a big message and with a grey overlay over the original page on the `document.onblur` event. this goes into affect with the user moves the mouse to click the close button. no luck if they ***alt+F4***