# javascript window.onbeforeunload not working in IE11

Tags: javascript

The following code works fine in Chrome, but not working in IE11. Is there anything wrong with this code? How to make it work in IE as well?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    var newLine = "\r\n";
    var message = "Line1";
    message += newLine;
    message += "Line2";
    return message;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crossbrowser onbeforeunload?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389554/crossbrowser-onbeforeunload)

Comment: Works in IE11 ... click "run" twice in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vqxvarej/

Comment: It doesn't get invoked if you close the browser with the X but is invoked when ran in Chrome.